# Protractor: why Page Object instance usually created on beforeEach(), can it be initialized once?

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, pageobjects

For most examples, I found for Protractor e2e tests, 'page object' initialized in `beforeEach()` function. I'm wondering why it's so common if the same page object instance (in most cases) can be used in all tests.
So instead:

```
let page: HomePage;
beforeEach(() => {
    page = new HomePage();
});
```

Can be just:

```
const page = new HomePage();
```

Comment: I bet it's because of state. Like you have in unit tests - you create new instance of tested class in each test or in ``beforeEach``. If your page object contains eg. only references to HTML elements I think it's not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Each test should be `ISOLATED` from each other. If you have construction `one file - one test` you could implement it like in your approach, just initialise once. If file has several amount of tests but they all have some common `Precondition` steps, they will be in `BeforeEach()` function.

Comment: Tests are isolated from each other, page navigation/refresh performed as well where needed. PO in most cases is helper class with functions to access page elements. It **does not** keep the instance of the page or object under test.

Comment: Agreed, it could be implemented in such way. Maybe, my vision is more object oriented and in my experience it easier to understand when you thinking about PO not as helper class only but more like an instance of the page. But you ask why :) and I gave explanation why people do it in such way.